# Find value at youngest date in list

Tags: python, list, datetime

I have this list of dates and amounts

```
dates_amount = [
    [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0), '15000.0'],
    [datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1, 0, 0), '10000.0'],
    [datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 1, 0, 0), '13000.0']]
```

I am trying to find the youngest date, i.e. the date which is closest from now, and retrieve the 2nd item from that sub-list. For the above example `7/1/2017` is the closest, so the answer should be `13000`. I wrote this code but it produces wrong output:

```
max_date = max(x[:-1] for x in enumerate(dates_amount))
max_amount = ''
for date,amount in dates_amount:
    if date == max_date:
       max_amount = amount
       break
print("Last Date: {} ".format(max_date))
print("Last Amount: {} ".format(max_amount))
```

The output I see is:

```
Last Date: (2,) 
Last Amount:
```

What is the mistake and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert some trivial tracing print statements, and you'll see the problem:

```
print ([x for x in enumerate(dates_amount)])
max_date = max(x[:-1] for x in enumerate(dates_amount))
print ("max_date", max_date)
```

Output:  # newlines inserted to help readability

```
[(0, [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0), '15000.0']), 
 (1, [datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1, 0, 0), '10000.0']),
 (2, [datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 1, 0, 0), '13000.0'])]
max_date (2,)
```

Now do you see the problem?  When you `enumerate` the list, you get tuples of (*index*, *value*).  With this representation, x[:-1] is all but the last element, which is the *index* of the item.  All you've done is to find the largest index in the list, which is simply an indirect way to find `len(dates_amount)`.

SOLUTION

Get rid of the enumeration.  All you need is

```
max_date = max(entry[0] for entry in dates_amount)
```

Perhaps even better is to sort with a key field and then grab the last element:

```
dates_amount.sort(key=lambda entry: entry[0])
print ("Last Amt:", dates_amount[-1][1])
```

Output:

```
Last Amt: 13000.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use a list of lists.  You want to use a dict.  You can transform your list of lists into a dict like so:

```
d = dict()
for l in dates_amount:
    d[l[0]] = l[1]
```

This will give you `d = {datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0): '15000.0', datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1, 0, 0): '10000.0', datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 1, 0, 0): '13000.0'}`

You can then find the maximum dict key with `max_key = max(d)` and the corresponding value with `d[max_key]`

Comment: You could create that dictionary just with `dict(dates_amount)`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your `max_date`, which you can see by the funky output that the print statement is giving you.

Since you do not get the date properly, the subsequent loop doesn't work as expected either.

An option to make this work would be:

```
max_date = max(x[0] for x in dates_amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
max_date, max_amount = max(dates_amount)
print("Last Date: {} ".format(max_date))
print("Last Amount: {} ".format(max_amount))
```

This uses the fact that list comparisons go element by element. If you prefer to be explicit, you can replace the first line with:

```
max_date, max_amount = max(dates_amount, key=lambda x: x[0])
```